# Avoid copying switch statments

Tags: c++, switch-statement, boilerplate

Can this code be refactored to avoid copying switch statements?

```
enum class Animal
{ Cat, Dog, Fish};

float GetMaxSpeed(Animal a)
{
 switch (a)
    {
        case Animal::Cat:
            return 30;
        case Animal::Dog:
            return 40;
        case Animal::Fish:
            return 15;
    }
 }

string GetGermanTranslation(Animal a)
{
 switch (a)
    {
        case Animal::Cat:
            return "Katze";
        case Animal::Dog:
            return "Hund";
        case Animal::Fish:
            return "Fische";
    }
 }
```

Obviously, this is a toy example, my real enum class is much larger.

Comment: Seems quite simple. Depending on the number of enum values, did you try simply using either a map or an array that enumerates the enum values, and gives the corresponding speed and translation? Or, if the enum values are guaranteed to be numerically consecutive, a simple array of both? No switch statements needed anywhere.

Comment: Consider using a different approach: `const AnimalData animalData[] = {{Animal::Cat, 30, "Katze"}, {Animal::Dog, 40, "Hund"}, {Animal::Fish, 15, "Fische"}};` - unfortunately C++ doesn't support the designated initializer syntax, `[Animal::Cat] = {30, "Katze"}`

Comment: @user253751 could you elaborate on this, preferably in an answer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks, that is also very useful. Is there any solution for when there is no direct mapping, for example if maximum speed is unknown?

Comment: A map (`std::map`) can be used to filter out sparse indices, but it seems an overkill. You can use `std::optional` for features that might be absent on some cases. Or you can use a `std::bitset` to keep track of existent features.

Answer (score 6):

A more object-oriented approach would consist of relying on *polymorphism* instead of continuously switching on an enumerator value representing a type.

To follow this approach, first, define an abstract class, `Animal`, that specifies the member functions its subclasses should implement:

```
class Animal {
public:
    virtual std::string GetGermanTranslation() const = 0;
    virtual float GetMaxSpeed() const = 0;
    virtual ~Animal() = default;
};
```

Then, publicly derive from this class and override the virtual member functions `GetGermanTranslation()` and `GetMaxSpeed()`.

For example, for `Cat`:

```
class Cat: public Animal {
public:
   std::string GetGermanTranslation() const override { return "Katze"; };
   float GetMaxSpeed() const override  { return 30; };
};
```

Then, similarly for `Dog`:

```
class Dog: public Animal {
public:
   std::string GetGermanTranslation() const override { return "Hund"; };
   float GetMaxSpeed() const override  { return 40; };
};
```

You can analogously define the `Fish` class.

Finally, having a pointer or reference to an `Animal` object, you just call the corresponding virtual member functions:

```
void displayAnimal(const Animal& animal) {
   std::cout << "The " << animal.GetGermanTranslation();
   std::cout << " runs at " << animal.GetMaxSpeed() << '\n';
}
```

As you can see, there is no more switching on an enumerator that represents a type for distinguishing the different animals.

You can call this function, `displayAnimal()`, with different `Animal` objects:

```
auto cat = std::make_unique<Cat>();
displayAnimal(*cat);

auto dog = std::make_unique<Dog>();
displayAnimal(*dog);
```

Comment: This is _way_ overkill. IMO an example of how not to do it. The switch is vastly simpler, faster, and easier to maintain. Also your solution is kind of orthogonal anyway; the OP has enum values not instances of things.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings This approach follows the [Open-closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) whereas the `switch` doesn't. For example, imagine that you have to **extend** the animals with a *mouse* animal: with the OOP approach, all you need to do is just to create a new class `Mouse` that derives from `Animal` and override the corresponding member functions. On the other hand, with the `switch` approach you will have to go through the whole code looking for all the `switch` statements and add a new case for every switch statement.

Comment: The polymorphic approach is extendible without modification of existing code, whereas the approach based on the `switch` statement requires modification of existing code for extending. The latter it's not only more work to do but also more error-prone. It is also less localized and spread across the whole code.

Comment: Incorrect. Compilers warn about missing enumerations in a switch. It's a very, very small job. You are vastly overengineering a very simple problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't specify otherwise, the first enumerator in an enumerated type has the value 0, and subsequent enumerators have a value that's one more than their predecessor. So with

```
enum Animal
{ Cat, Dog, Fish};
```

the value of `Cat` is 0, the value of `Dog` is 1, and the value of `Fish` is 2. To map those values to some other set of values, just use them as an array index:

```
int max_speed[] = {
    30, 40, 15
};

const char* german_name[] = {
    "Katze",
    "Hund",
    "Fische"
};
```

Now you can write things like `max_speed[Cat]` and `german_name[Dog]`.

Note that the string literals are inside **double** quotes, e.g., `"Katze"`, not single quotes as in the question. Single quotes around multiple characters create a funky thing called a "multicharacter literal". They're pretty much useless.

Comment: This is very useful, but in my real-world case i want the have explicit, readable, mappings between the enums and their properties.